# Redirect on empty result in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, http-status-code-404, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I'm fairly new to Rails development, please forgive my naivety :).

I'm using the Comfortable Mexican Sofa CMS for my rails application. Currently, I've got a vanilla installation without any changes to files. I'm trying to accomplish something pretty general and powerful, and I think it can only be done in a controller for it to be correct - I'm trying to make all empty database query results redirect to a landing page rather than give a 404.

Ideally, I'd like to make this work for a resource controller, and only apply this to the `show` method.

From the looks of it, `Comfy::Cms::Site Load` calls `rescue` when `page_not_found` is called. To me, this looks like the internal 404 handling is baked into Comfortable Mexican Sofa, which isn't ideal. Is there a way to add a `before_action`, or something similar to my main application controller to accomplish what I'm trying? Thank you for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Sofa is using route globbing to serve content. So it decides what to do when page is not found. Easiest way to override this is to:

- run `rails g comfy:cms:controllers`. (available as of 1.12.3)
- find `app/comfy/cms/controllers/content_controller.rb` (delete rest of the files as you don't need them)
- change `page_not_found` method to redirect or do whatever you want.

Hope this helps.

Edit:

Alternatively you can rescue from a RoutingError (this is what CMS will throw if doesn't find a page, and there's no 404 page)

```
# in your application_controller.rb
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :your_method_with_redirect
```

Comment: That's actually exactly what I did haha. I can't seem to get `rescue_from` to actually work from the ActionCrontroller! Even when pattern matching against `Exception`, I still can't catch it! I'm wondering if Sofa is delimiting the scope somehow during the pattern matching phase.